Yolov8 freezes during training
I'm trying to train a Yolov8 model, but am facing some weird behaviors which I'm not sure the reason. During training, it freezes on 71% and doesn't continue. What is the issue?
I tried rebooting the machine and re-installing Ultralytics and Pytorch, but that didn't help.
Ultralytics YOLOv8.2.1  Python-3.8.10 torch-2.2.2+cu121 CPU (Intel Xeon Gold 6330 2.00GHz)
engine/trainer: task=classify, mode=train, model=yolov8s-cls.pt, data=/home/mydata, epochs=2, time=None, patience=100, batch=16, imgsz=320, save=True, save_period=-1, cache=False, device=None, workers=8, project=None, name=train3, exist_ok=False, pretrained=True, optimizer=auto, verbose=True, seed=0, deterministic=True, single_cls=False, rect=False, cos_lr=False, close_mosaic=10, resume=False, amp=True, fraction=1.0, profile=False, freeze=None, multi_scale=False, overlap_mask=True, mask_ratio=4, dropout=0.0, val=True, split=val, save_json=False, save_hybrid=False, conf=None, iou=0.7, max_det=300, half=False, dnn=False, plots=True, source=None, vid_stride=1, stream_buffer=False, visualize=False, augment=False, agnostic_nms=False, classes=None, retina_masks=False, embed=None, show=False, save_frames=False, save_txt=False, save_conf=False, save_crop=False, show_labels=True, show_conf=True, show_boxes=True, line_width=None, format=torchscript, keras=False, optimize=False, int8=False, dynamic=False, simplify=False, opset=None, workspace=4, nms=False, lr0=0.01, lrf=0.01, momentum=0.937, weight_decay=0.0005, warmup_epochs=3.0, warmup_momentum=0.8, warmup_bias_lr=0.1, box=7.5, cls=0.5, dfl=1.5, pose=12.0, kobj=1.0, label_smoothing=0.0, nbs=64, hsv_h=0.015, hsv_s=0.7, hsv_v=0.4, degrees=0.0, translate=0.1, scale=0.5, shear=0.0, perspective=0.0, flipud=0.0, fliplr=0.5, bgr=0.0, mosaic=1.0, mixup=0.0, copy_paste=0.0, auto_augment=randaugment, erasing=0.4, crop_fraction=1.0, cfg=None, tracker=botsort.yaml, save_dir=runs/classify/train3
train: /home/mydata/train... found 310575 images in 13 classes ✅ 
val: /home/mydata/val... found 34515 images in 13 classes ✅ 
test: None...
Overriding model.yaml nc=1000 with nc=13
                   from  n    params  module                                       arguments                     
  0                  -1  1       928  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [3, 32, 3, 2]                 
  1                  -1  1     18560  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [32, 64, 3, 2]                
  2                  -1  1     29056  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [64, 64, 1, True]             
  3                  -1  1     73984  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [64, 128, 3, 2]               
  4                  -1  2    197632  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [128, 128, 2, True]           
  5                  -1  1    295424  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [128, 256, 3, 2]              
  6                  -1  2    788480  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [256, 256, 2, True]           
  7                  -1  1   1180672  ultralytics.nn.modules.conv.Conv             [256, 512, 3, 2]              
  8                  -1  1   1838080  ultralytics.nn.modules.block.C2f             [512, 512, 1, True]           
  9                  -1  1    674573  ultralytics.nn.modules.head.Classify         [512, 13]                     
YOLOv8s-cls summary: 99 layers, 5097389 parameters, 5097389 gradients, 12.6 GFLOPs
Transferred 156/158 items from pretrained weights
train: Scanning /home/mydata/train... 220553 images, 0 corrupt:  71%|███████   | 220530/310575 [02:19<00:43, 2078.17it/s]

